# Error while import data from mysql backup file

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

```
Using mysqldump npm module.While import the backfile generated using this npm.Get this error.

var mysqlDump = require('mysqldump');

mysqlDump({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test',
    tables:[], // only these tables
    dest:'./data.sql' // destination file
},function(err){
    // create data.sql file;
})
```

> Error :
>
> "11:28:40 Restoring C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\dumps\xx24052018.sql
>       Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\temp\tmptdzvot.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\dumps\xxxx24052018.sql"
>       ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
>
> ```
> Operation failed with exitcode 1
> 11:28:41 Import of C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\dumps\xxxx24052018.sql has finished with 1 errors"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Error says

> *No database selected*

Are you sure about all db settings?

Comment: yes.All db settings are fine .
When I see the scripts of manual dbbackup file there are two lines which are missing while using this script.
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `databaseName` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `databaseName`;